# How to use both GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration and a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have some API, several resources should be available to everyone, the rest for users.

I to proctect resources I have implemented a class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .authenticationManagerResolver((request) -> http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class))
            .and().oauth2Login()
            .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and().cors();
    }
}
```

And then I was trying to follow https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access to allow some of resources be accessible to everyone

So I did according to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510133/can-i-use-both-a-globalmethodsecurityconfiguration-and-a-websecurityconfigurerad/36344400)

`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` & `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
{
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return new CustomPermissionAllowedMethodSecurityMetadataSource();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .authenticationManagerResolver((request) -> http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class))
                .and().oauth2Login()
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and().cors();
        }
    }
}
```

and the implementation of `CustomPermissionAllowedMethodSecurityMetadataSource`

```
public class CustomPermissionAllowedMethodSecurityMetadataSource extends AbstractFallbackMethodSecurityMetadataSource
{

    @Override
    protected Collection<ConfigAttribute> findAttributes(Method method, Class<?> targetClass)
    {
        Annotation[] annotations = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(method);
        List attributes = new ArrayList<>();

        // if the class is annotated as @Controller we should by default deny access to all methods
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(targetClass, Controller.class) != null)
        {
            attributes.add(DENY_ALL_ATTRIBUTE);
        }

        if (annotations != null)
        {
            for (Annotation a : annotations)
            {
                // but not if the method has at least a PreAuthorize or PostAuthorize annotation
                if (a instanceof PreAuthorize || a instanceof PostAuthorize)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return attributes;
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<ConfigAttribute> findAttributes(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

At the end I have added to the endpoint in rest controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
```

Unfortunately, without a user, I cannot access this endpoint.

Do I use GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration and a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter wrong?

Is it a correct way to achieve what I mentioned at the beginning (some endpoints protected, some not)?

Comment: Are you sure that the first configuration without `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` let a not authenticated request access your controller? Because your configuration is: `.anyRequest().authenticated()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the difference between `Method Security` and `Http Security`.

`Method security` is how to protect methods internally from being called. This is usually used in for instance client applications, desktop applications etc. Here you place an annotation on a specific `method` and will protect it from being called internally.

`HttpSecurity` is an implementation that deals with how to protect http api endpoints. This is usually done with preimplemented filters in spring boot and this is what you should be looking at, not `method security`.

You have currently implemented `method security` and trying to protect http endpoints using it.

I suggest you start with the [spring security hello world java configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc) part in the official documentation to learn how to implement `HttpSecurity` in spring boot. Or here is another [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication).

And here is an example

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
          .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/securityNone").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

this configuration permits all requests to `/securityNone` and sets all other endpoints to need authentication.